# Put a meta link for the current site in the Android app's side bar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app, per-site-meta

Currently, the only way I know of to visit a site's meta via the Android app (1.0.16) is to pin its meta to my sites in the sidebar. *It's a really good thing I can do this* for the metas I visit frequently, and I don't want to see it go, but it's also inconvenient if it's the *only* way to reach a meta.

Could we have a sidebar item that takes us to the meta site for whatever SE site we currently have open? (Or, if we're already in their meta, to their main site)

To illustrate my point, here's a before & after:

[image: before] [image: after]

Comment: Yes Please. I for one needs this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We've talked a lot about this internally and have decided to not do implement this at the moment.

The reasoning comes out from two points:

1. The navigation bar should not be context specific to the current view. It's confusing when the contents of a sliding panel change based on what you're presently looking at, and doing this would be a drastic change for the navigation bar.
2. This is a power-user only feature, and although we implement a *lot* of power-user centric features this one doesn't make much sense because if you're someone who already knows what a meta site is you most likely know that there's an "EDIT" button next the "Your Sites" field too.

At the end of the day, I can't really think of this being a positive gain since it'll confuse new people a lot (it'll take some practice to realize sliding the navigation drawer from different places does different things) and the field *right* below it is customizable to remedy this situation.

One minor note: We have discussed completely redoing the navigation of the application to turn taps on an item in "YOUR SITES" from displaying the site to popping something open below the item that lets you have easy access to questions, tags, users, favorite tags, etc. If we do end up doing this (which I think we will) then adding a meta link here will be an obvious move.

Comment: I don't understand this decision. Going to the meta site isn't that rare an action. I don't want to put meta sites in my quick list — *that* would be an ultra-power-user feature, and it would pollute a list for no benefit on the main site. I find it very counterintuitive that the meta link isn't roughly at the same location as on the main site — in the menu that appears when clicking/tapping the top left corner, which is otherwise fairly similar. I don't understand the part about “sliding the navigation drawer from different places does different things” bit: it should show meta/main always.

Comment: I don't understand this either.  I navigate between main and meta all the time -- via the web interface.  That there is no affordance in the app is a major reason that I pretty much only use the app for getting notifications right now.  I'm not going to go all the way to my "all accounts" list, toggle *that* to meta, and then go back to my site every single time I want to switch views.

Comment: Is that ‘taps on an item in "YOUR SITES"’ thing [what has just been announced on iOS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229369/provide-a-link-to-per-site-meta/251507#251507)? Will that be done on Android too? And can we please have an easily discoverable way as well?

Comment: Another place to put it would be the menu that pops up if you tap the site name at the top of the UI.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298074/260800