# Where are all the meta sites?

Tags: support, android-app

How do I get to the meta sites on the Android app? There only appears to be the main Stack Exchange meta in the list of sites...

[image]

Comment: cough "main sites button" cough

Comment: There they are. Maybe I should have tagged this as *blind* instead of support. Thanks

Comment: You can tag it as status-completed, now.

Comment: The UI has changed since this question was asked.  I found this question because I, too, cannot figure out how to navigate to a site's meta -- I'm on the site's questions page and I see *no path* to meta.  Not in the header, not in the site list -- if I go to "your sites" it shows me all the metas (or so it appears) *and adds them to my list*, which is heavyweight.  How do I just plain navigate?

Comment: @MonicaCellio http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223092/put-a-meta-link-for-the-current-site-in-the-android-apps-side-bar/223241#223241