# Convenient button to switch between main site and meta site on the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, per-site-meta

Currently, to switch from a main site to its meta (and vice versa), one needs to search for the other site in the side bar. I think we can make the process more convenient of the switch button is included in the drop down on the question lists.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a workaround. You can easily switch between sites if you add them to **your sites** list:

> [image: sites]